# iOS Provisioning Profile (InHouse) Enterprise

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

I have some expired Provisioning Profile for InHouse App (Enterprise) in my Apple Developer Account.

What is the effect if i delete those Provisioning Profile?
Will it affected the published app?
Is it safe to delete it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just delete them:

- Installed apps will continue running on devices
- Current archives can still be installed on devices (from your enterprise server / enterprise app store)
- But you will not be able to archive (e.g. distribute) new versions of your  App any more.

Nevertheless, you can download them from Apple again (by means of Xcode -> Settings -> Accounts), if you change your mind in the future.